# Yeoman webapp not showing in the yo list

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm currently having a play with Yeoman using an online tutorial. Having installed node and yeoman I added the webapp generator but when I run yo in the terminal, the webapp isn't listed as expected. The generator is actually created in

```
/Users/jonmacbook/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp
```

which doesn't seem correct if it needs to be accessed globally

Here is the code that is outputted in full when I install the generator

```
Last login: Mon Dec 30 20:55:07 on ttys000
            ➜  ~  desk
            ➜  Desktop  cd yeoman-dema
            ➜  yeoman-dema  yo webapp
            Error webapp

            You don't seem to have a generator with the name webapp installed.
            You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
            To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
            ➜  yeoman-dema  npm search yeoman-generator
            npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
            npm http 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
            npm ERR! Error: illegal_database_name Name: 'error.html'. Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter.: -/all
            npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:275:14)
            npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
            npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
            npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:893:14)
            npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
            npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:844:12)
            npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
            npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
            npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
            npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
            npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
            npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

            npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
            npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "search" "yeoman-generator"
            npm ERR! cwd /Users/jonmacbook/Desktop/yeoman-dema
            npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
            npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
            npm ERR!
            npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
            npm ERR!     /Users/jonmacbook/Desktop/yeoman-dema/npm-debug.log
            npm ERR! not ok code 0
            ➜  yeoman-dema  clear
            ➜  yeoman-dema  ~
            ➜  ~  npm install -g generator-webapp
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp/-/generator-webapp-0.4.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp/-/generator-webapp-0.4.6.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator/-/yeoman-generator-0.14.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator/-/yeoman-generator-0.14.2.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio/-/cheerio-0.12.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio/-/cheerio-0.12.4.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio-select
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2/3.1.4
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dargs
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/download
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/file-utils
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.4.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio-select
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio-select/-/cheerio-select-0.0.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2/3.1.4
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2/-/htmlparser2-3.1.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/entities/-/entities-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.2.5.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/diff/-/diff-1.0.8.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.4.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio-select/-/cheerio-select-0.0.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2/-/htmlparser2-3.1.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/entities/-/entities-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-0.7.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.2.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/dargs
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff/-/diff-1.0.8.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dargs/-/dargs-0.1.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile/-/isbinaryfile-0.1.9.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.2.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-0.7.4.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.2.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.2.11.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile/-/isbinaryfile-0.1.9.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string/-/underscore.string-2.3.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/dargs/-/dargs-0.1.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.2.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.2.7.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync/-/findup-sync-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/-/chalk-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs/-/shelljs-0.2.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.2.11.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer/-/inquirer-0.3.5.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table/-/text-table-0.2.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/download
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string/-/underscore.string-2.3.3.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/download/-/download-0.1.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs/-/shelljs-0.2.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync/-/findup-sync-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/-/chalk-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/file-utils
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/file-utils/-/file-utils-0.1.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer/-/inquirer-0.3.5.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.9.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table/-/text-table-0.2.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/download/-/download-0.1.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/file-utils/-/file-utils-0.1.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.9.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.27.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.27.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSselect
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSselect
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSselect/-/CSSselect-0.4.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSselect/-/CSSselect-0.4.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype/-/domelementtype-1.1.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils/-/domutils-1.1.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype/-/domelementtype-1.1.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.0.17.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils/-/domutils-1.1.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.0.17.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler/-/domhandler-2.0.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler/-/domhandler-2.0.3.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSwhat
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils/-/domutils-1.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils/-/domutils-1.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSwhat
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSwhat/-/CSSwhat-0.4.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/through2
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/each-async
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.25.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSwhat/-/CSSwhat-0.4.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.1.21.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-1.0.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/each-async
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.25.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/each-async/-/each-async-0.1.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/through2
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color/-/has-color-0.1.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress/-/decompress-0.1.5.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-0.2.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/through2/-/through2-0.1.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.1.21.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-1.0.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/each-async/-/each-async-0.1.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress/-/decompress-0.1.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-0.2.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color/-/has-color-0.1.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/through2/-/through2-0.1.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.14.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.14.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.1.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-color
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/0.0.3
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-1.2.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.1.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-color
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-1.2.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-color/-/cli-color-0.2.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/0.0.3
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe/-/json-stringify-safe-5.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/-/mute-stream-0.0.3.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent/-/tunnel-agent-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent/-/forever-agent-0.5.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.6.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign/-/oauth-sign-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature/-/http-signature-0.10.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign/-/aws-sign-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data/-/form-data-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent/-/tunnel-agent-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-color/-/cli-color-0.2.3.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar/-/cookie-jar-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/-/mute-stream-0.0.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe/-/json-stringify-safe-5.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent/-/forever-agent-0.5.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign/-/oauth-sign-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign/-/aws-sign-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature/-/http-signature-0.10.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data/-/form-data-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar/-/cookie-jar-0.3.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-1.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-1.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.5.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.5.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/temp
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner/-/stream-combiner-0.0.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/temp
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/temp/-/temp-0.6.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip/-/adm-zip-0.4.3.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout/-/mout-0.6.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.19.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend/-/xtend-2.0.6.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-1.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner/-/stream-combiner-0.0.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/temp/-/temp-0.6.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mout/-/mout-0.6.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.19.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip/-/adm-zip-0.4.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend/-/xtend-2.0.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-1.0.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.2.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream/-/combined-stream-0.0.4.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.2.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/-/asn1-0.1.11.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/-/assert-plus-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream/-/combined-stream-0.0.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/-/ctype-0.5.2.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-object
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/-/asn1-0.1.11.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/-/assert-plus-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/-/ctype-0.5.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-object
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-object/-/is-object-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
            npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys/-/object-keys-0.2.0.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-object/-/is-object-0.1.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys/-/object-keys-0.2.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles/-/cryptiles-0.2.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp/-/sntp-0.2.4.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-0.4.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles/-/cryptiles-0.2.2.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/foreach
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp/-/sntp-0.2.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-0.4.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/foreach
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof/-/indexof-0.0.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/foreach/-/foreach-2.0.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is/-/is-0.2.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/foreach/-/foreach-2.0.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof/-/indexof-0.0.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is/-/is-0.2.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/es5-ext
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/memoizee
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/memoizee
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/memoizee/-/memoizee-0.2.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/es5-ext
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/es5-ext/-/es5-ext-0.9.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/memoizee/-/memoizee-0.2.6.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/es5-ext/-/es5-ext-0.9.2.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.0.3
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer/-/duplexer-0.1.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.0.3
            npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.1.4.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.0.3.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer/-/duplexer-0.1.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream/-/block-stream-0.0.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.1.4.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-0.1.25.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.0.3.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/next-tick
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream/-/block-stream-0.0.7.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-0.1.25.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/next-tick
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/next-tick/-/next-tick-0.1.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter/-/event-emitter-0.2.2.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/next-tick/-/next-tick-0.1.0.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter/-/event-emitter-0.2.2.tgz
            npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-2.0.1.tgz
            npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-2.0.1.tgz
            generator-webapp@0.4.6 /Users/jonmacbook/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp
            ├── cheerio@0.12.4 (entities@0.3.0, underscore@1.4.4, cheerio-select@0.0.3, htmlparser2@3.1.4)
            └── yeoman-generator@0.14.2 (dargs@0.1.0, diff@1.0.8, debug@0.7.4, rimraf@2.2.5, text-table@0.2.0, mime@1.2.11, async@0.2.9, mkdirp@0.3.5, isbinaryfile@0.1.9, shelljs@0.2.6, chalk@0.3.0, underscore.string@2.3.3, iconv-lite@0.2.11, lodash@2.2.1, glob@3.2.7, findup-sync@0.1.2, request@2.27.0, file-utils@0.1.5, inquirer@0.3.5, download@0.1.7)
            ➜  ~  yo
            [?] What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
            ❯ Install a generator
              Find some help
              Get me out of here!
```

Why would Yeoman install in the wrong part of my machine instead of the usr/local/share/npm folder that the video tutorial indicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the generator [globally](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) ?
**-g** in npm install invocation: `npm install -g generator-webapp`.
Additionally it has to be executed with admin privileges.

Comment: I added the local node prefix as suggested by this post.
    echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc removing that from the .npmrc file fixed the problem